# jq: select without dropping items from array

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON file which looks like this (a rough schema):

```
[{
    "custom_variables": [
        {
            "name": "xxx",
            "value": "xxx"
        },
        {
            "name": "xxx",
            "value": "xxx"
        },
        {
            "name": "profile_id",
            "value": "123"
        }
    ],
    // many fields
    "xxx": "xxx",
    "xxx": "xxx",
    "xxx": "xxx"
}]
```

I am using jq to extract all the fields from the top level object. The custom_variables field constains an array of objects with name and value.

I want to extract a specific object from custom_variables, given its name.

So what I am doing is this:

```
jq 'map(
    {
        xxx: .xxx, 
        xxx: .xxx, 
        xxx: .xxx, 
        xxx: .custom_variables | .[] | select(.name == "variable_name")
    } 
)'
```

It almost works; it gets the variable I want when it exists, but when it doesn't (or if custom_variables itself doesn't) it will drop the whole top-level object. So in the end I am getting less objects then I put into the script.

How can I just return null if I don't find that field but still keep the rest of the data?

Answer (score 1):

Use the alternative operator (`//`) to transform a stream of zero elements (such as those which can be generated by `select` or `.[]`) into a value:

```
jq 'map(
    {
        xxx: .xxx, 
        xxx: .xxx, 
        xxx: .xxx, 
        xxx: .custom_variables | .[] | select(.name == "variable_name") // null
    } 
)'
```

This will have `.xxx` be `null` when there is a zero-element stream on the left side of `//`.

You can, of course, place the alternative operator at a different position to capture the zero-element stream at an earlier or later stage, such as at the object level:

```
jq 'map(
    {
        xxx: .xxx, 
        xxx: .xxx, 
        xxx: .xxx, 
        xxx: .custom_variables | .[] | select(.name == "variable_name")
    } // {}
)'
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it looks ugly. Any better solutions?

```
custom_variables: (if (.custom_variables | length > 0) 
            then (.custom_variables | .[]? | select(.name == "variable_name") | .value | scan("\\d+"))
            else null
            end)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following does what you've indicated you want, as best as I can understand your
requirements.

```
map( if .custom_variables
     then .custom_variables |= (map(select(.name == "variable_name") | .value)
                                | .[0]) 
     else .
     end )
```

Example input:

```
[{
    "custom_variables": [
        {
            "name": "xxx",
            "value": "xxx"
        },
        {
            "name": "xxx",
            "value": "xxx"
        },
        {
            "name": "variable_name",
            "value": "123"
        }
    ],
    "xxx1": "xxx",
    "xxx2": "xxx",
    "xxx3": "xxx"
},

{
    "yyy1": "yyy",
    "yyy2": "yyy",
    "yyy3": "yyy"
}
]
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "custom_variables": "123",
    "xxx1": "xxx",
    "xxx2": "xxx",
    "xxx3": "xxx"
  },
  {
    "yyy1": "yyy",
    "yyy2": "yyy",
    "yyy3": "yyy"
  }
]
```